# Use a byte flag to indicate non-null pointers

Tags: c++

I'm reading [this](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/introduction-to-octrees-r3529) article about Octrees and I noticed the author uses a byte variable to hold information about active child nodes for every Octree node.

```
byte m_activeNodes = 0;
```

He then uses it as follows

```
//Create child nodes
for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++)
{
    if (octList[a].Count != 0)
    {
        m_childNode[a] = CreateNode(octant[a], octList[a]);
        m_activeNodes |= (byte)(1 << a);
        m_childNode[a].BuildTree();
    }
}
```

Then in the rest of the code, whenever he wants to check if an active node of an octree exists, he first checks `m_activeNodes`, and then accessing `m_childNode[index]` without worries.
Example:

```
//recursively update any child nodes.
for( int flags = m_activeNodes, index = 0; flags > 0; flags >>=1, index++)
    if ((flags & 1) == 1) m_childNode[index].Update(gameTime);
```

The author codes in C# and not in C++, but I know I would just set non-active nodes to `nullptr` and then check if `m_childNodes[index] == nullptr` before accessing it.

So my question is if his approach is more efficient than mine, and if not, what benefits does it have.

Comment: My guess would be, the point of the exercise is to quickly check whether *any* child node exists. I presume it's somehow significant to the algorithm (which I'm not familiar with).

Comment: I'd concur. This seems like an easy way of checking if you're dealing with a leaf node (`!m_activeNodes`) or one that has to be traversed. That would side-step your loop entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The byte field is not there as a "safety check" - it's there as an optimisation.  It provides him with a trivial check as to whether the current node is a leaf node (with no children) without having to check each child pointer individually.

Even if there are leaf nodes, the field also allows the loop to terminate as soon as the last child is found, instead of checking all 8 potential children.